# Disable long press for Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to disable long press gestures for the flutter WebView package:
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

I've found that by wrapping the web view in a GestureDetector I'm able to prevent this, which works fine. However, after the first long press then scrolling in the web view no longer works correctly.

Sorry if this has been answered before but I can't find any info on how to do this, nor figure out a way to do it myself.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after much trial and error I finally figured it out

Basically you need to set and reuse the WebViewController (this is set in `onWebViewCreated`) and then inside of `onPageFinished` you can inject your JavaScript string using `evaluateJavascript` function on that controller.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();
}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  WebViewController _webViewController;

  String jsString = 'document.addEventListener("contextmenu", event => event.preventDefault());';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'Your URL goes here',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async {
          _webViewController = webViewController;
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(jsString);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class _CourseReadState extends State<CourseRead> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  WebViewController? _webViewController;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  String jsString =
      'document.addEventListener("contextmenu", event => event.preventDefault());';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return BlocBuilder<CourseReadBloc, CourseReadState>(
      
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is CourseReadLoaded) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyAppBar(height: 60.h, title: 'title'),
            body: WebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
              gestureRecognizers: {
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                ),
              },
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async {
                _webViewController = webViewController;
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onPageFinished: (_) {
                _webViewController!.runJavascriptReturningResult(jsString);
              },
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
                state.html,
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
              ).toString(),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state is CourseReadError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyAppBar(height: 60.h, title: 'title'),
            body: Center(child: Text(state.error)),
          );
        }
        return const Scaffold(body: progressIndicator);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).