# How can I disable the long press for Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I'm looking for a way to disable the long press function on webview_flutter. I found only one post about using the evaluateJavascript for do that, but it's not working for me. Any tip? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable long press for Flutter WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141322/disable-long-press-for-flutter-webview)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have tried, but it isn't worked for me.